# Prove that function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, rouches-theorem

> Let $F(x,y)$ be a holomorphic function of two variables without zeroes
>   on $|x|=1$, $\phi(x)$ be a holomorphic function on a disk. Consider
>   function $\mbox{Ф}$ that sends point $y_0$ to $\sum\phi(\alpha_i)$,
>   where $\alpha_i$ are zeroes of $F(x,y_0)$ in $|x|\leq1$ with
>   multiplicities. Prove that $\mbox{Ф}$ is holomorphic.

It looks like the proof is somehow related to Rouche's theorem but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Residue Theorem to express $\Phi(y)$ as the contour integral of a meromorphic function around the unit circle.

Comment: $\mbox{Ф}(y_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|x|\leq 1} \frac{F'(x,y_0)}{F(x,y_0)} z^k dz = \sum\alpha_i^k$ and it is holomorphic since $F$ has no zeroes on a boundary, right?

Comment: Not quite, but close.  You want $\phi(x) \; dx$ instead of $z^k \; dz$, and $|x|=1$ (with positive orientation) not $|x| \le 1$.